# What does shell command ls [abc]*e*? search for?

Tags: linux, shell

What files is the Linux shell command

```
ls [abc]*e*?
```

Going to look for?

Answer (score 1):

First, be aware that, while many other commands use *regular expressions*, `ls` uses *globs*.  Let's break down what the glob  `[abc]*e*?` matches:

1. `[abc]` matches one character chosen from set a, b ,or c.
2. `*` matches any number of any character
3. `e` matches `e`.
4. `*` matches any number of any character.
5. `?` matches any one character.

For example, consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
a1w2e3z41  ae1  af1  de1
```

The matches among these to the glob are:

```
$ ls [abc]*e*?
a1w2e3z41  ae1
```

Comment: The purpose of the `'?'` following the `'e*'` being that the filename **not** end in `'e'` alone (e.g. `abcde`, `abcdee`, will only display`abcdee`) Also note with the *character class like* glob `[..]`, you can negate the match by including the *circumflex* as the first character (e.g. `[^abc]` will only match files **not** beginning with `abc`)